# Computing the following contour Integral of a non analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $$\int_{|\frac{2z-1}{2-z}|=1}(\bar{z}^4-\bar{z}^3)(e^z){^2}$$

How can I compute this? The contour is very confusing, it just consists of two points $z=\pm1$ and the function is not analytic. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is that contour supposed to be $|(2z-1)/(2-z)| = 1$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, the equal sign shouldve been outside the modulus.

Comment: The contour is a circle or a line, because $(2z-1)/(2-z)$ is a Möbius transformation, so its inverse also is, and the image of a circle under a Möbius transformation is either a circle or a line. Here, it is a circle.

Comment: why are we interested in inverses of such contours? @ThomasAndrews

Comment: The set of $z$ such that $|f(z)|=1$ is all $f^{-1}(w)$ where $|w|=1.$ @BrazyOski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set$$\left\{z\in\Bbb C\,\middle|\,\left|\frac{2z-1}{2-z}\right|=1\right\}$$is the unit circle. Therefore, your integral is simply$$\oint_{|z|=1}\left(\overline z^4-\overline z^3\right)(e^z)^2\,\mathrm dz=\oint_{|z|=1}\left(\frac1{z^4}-\frac1{z^3}\right)e^{2z}\,\mathrm dz.$$Since the residue of $\left(\frac1{z^4}-\frac1{z^3}\right)e^{2z}$ at $0$ is $-\frac23$,$$\oint_{|z|=1}\left(\frac1{z^4}-\frac1{z^3}\right)e^{2z}\,\mathrm dz=-\frac{4\pi i}3.$$

Comment: Oh that's cute. It's hiding the fact that it's equal to a meromorphic function at every point of the contour.

Comment: This assumes the direction of the contour is counter-clockwise, but the function $z\mapsto (2z-1)/(z-2)$ reverses the direction.  It is unclear really what the original question means, however, under the usual assumptions. Does $(2z-1)/(z-2)$ go around the circle counterclockwise, or does $z$ do so?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Good point! Let us see whether the OP adds more details.